# ASP.NET: HtmlGenericControl("div") or Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, panel

Is there any difference in overhead between using `Panel` or `HtmlContainerControl` when needing to create a serverside container in ASP.NET.

```
HtmlContainerControl Container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Or

```
Panel Container = new Panel();
```

Also, are there any differences in how it is rendered in different browsers? I've noticed that Panel seems to render as a div in all browsers I have used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) supports extra functionality such as Direction, BackImageUrl, ScrollBars, etc... However if all you need is a div, I would use [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx).

It is explicit which makes for **better code readability**. It also gives you more control over the markup, e.g. you may not agree with how something like BackImageUrl has been implemented by Microsoft.